# WPF saving inputs & updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I've already got the the point where I can save all inputs to a text file but now I would like to create another feature where I can update that file but only through the form itself

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string lb1 = "";
    string lb = "";
    //Removes listboxtitem object name
    ListBoxItem mySelectedItem0 = listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem mySelectedItem1 = listBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;

    if (mySelectedItem0 != null && mySelectedItem1 != null)
    {
        lb1 = mySelectedItem1.Content.ToString();
        lb = mySelectedItem0.Content.ToString();

    }



    TextWriter saveText = new StreamWriter(@"D:\blah.txt");
    saveText.Write("===================================[Receipt]===================================" + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Title:" + " " + comboBox.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Surname:" + " " + textBox1.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Forname:" + " " + textBox2.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Passanger[s]:" + " " +  textBox6.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Group:" + " " + checkBox.IsChecked + "  " + "No: " + textBox4.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Class:" + " " + comboBox1.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Luggage:" + " " + textBox7.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Suitcase:" + " " + checkBox1.IsChecked + "  " + "No: " +textBox5.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Departure On:" + "  " + DatePicker.Text + " " + "At:" + "  " +comboBox2.Text + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("|Destination From:" + " " + lb + " " + "To:" + " " + lb1 + "\r\n");
    saveText.Write("===================================[Receipt]===================================");




    saveText.Close();
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\blah.txt", Environment.NewLine);

}
```

so here it safes all inputs and values as strings into a blah.txt file, how can I now retrieve all information from the file into the form and update it?

Comment: File.ReadLines or ... there are many ways just read [File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) and look also to the See Also section

Comment: Please read about MVVM before continuing further on the path you have chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the entire content of a text file by using [ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) function. Also, you can condense your text construction:

```
String ticketText = String.Format(@"
===================================[Receipt]====================================
|Title: {0}
|Surname: {1}
|Forname: {2} 
...
...

", comboBox.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, ...);

saveText.Write(ticketText);
```

This way of constructing your text is better since everything is done at once and it is easier to read. This will be made even easier when with [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Also I recommend naming your control by their meaning: e.g. `txtTitle` or `TitleText` for `Title`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using 2 different methods to write to a file in one process. You use a `StreamWriter` to save the receipt. And then static `File.AppendAllText` to attach an empty line. No need to do that. I think it would be better to generate the message in a separate method and then use the static `File.AppendAllText` to save everything in one go:

```
private string GetReceipt()
{
    StringBuilder receiptBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("===================================[Receipt]===================================");
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Title:" + " " + comboBox.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Surname:" + " " + textBox1.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Forname:" + " " + textBox2.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Passanger[s]:" + " " + textBox6.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Group:" + " " + checkBox.IsChecked + "  " + "No: " + textBox4.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Class:" + " " + comboBox1.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Luggage:" + " " + textBox7.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Suitcase:" + " " + checkBox1.IsChecked + "  " + "No: " + textBox5.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Departure On:" + "  " + DatePicker.Text + " " + "At:" + "  " + comboBox2.Text);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("|Destination From:" + " " + lb + " " + "To:" + " " + lb1);
    receiptBuilder.AppendLine("===================================[Receipt]===================================");

    receiptBuilder.AppendLine();

    return receiptBuilder.ToString();
}
```

And then save to the file:

```
File.AppendAllText(filePath, GetReceipt());
```

With this small refactoring you can now easily achieve first part of your request: Updating the existing file.

When you need to update the file with new data you simply invoke the `GetReceipt()` and append the results.

Or if you need the old file to be erased then you can use `WriteAllText` instead:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, GetReceipt());
```

Now the reading of the file. Depends what you need. If you just read the text and display it in a text box then it's fairly easy. Just use `ReadAllText`

```
myTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

However if you want to display it in appropriate combo boxes and text boxes then you would have to manually read the file. But if that's the case then I'd encourage you to refactor your code a little bit:

Create a class that holds all the information of the receipt. Each time you want to save your data create a new instance of this class and then serialize it (or save to a database) so it's easy to retrieve specific fields. If you still want to have a nice way to display a receipt you can override the `ToString` method.